# How do I match for symbols like < and > with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing a log file, and I am trying to match for expressions like `"key"=>"value"` to extract the value. I can't figure out how to match for the greater than symbol.

I am not having any luck with `re.match(r">", ...)`, `r"\>"`, or `r"\\r"`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re.match only matches from the start of the string.   try re.search:

```
>>> re.match(">", "a>b")
>>> re.search(">", "a>b")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4dd577e3d8>
```

or match the other text first:

```
>>> re.match(".*>", "a>b")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4dd577e440>
```